# Error using turtle under Python 2.7 Idle

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

Why is my code showing an error in turtle()?  I am using Python 2.7.13 Idle.  The query is regarding to draw a square using turtle:

```
import turtle
def draw_square():
 window=turtle.Screen()
 window.bgcolor("red")
 brad= turtle.Turtle()
 brad.shape("yellow") # move forward
 brad.speed(2)# turn pen right 90 degrees
 brad.forward(100)
 brad.right(90)
 brad.forward(100)
 brad.right(90)
 brad.forward(100)
 brad.right(90)
 brad.forward(100)
 brad.right(90)
window.exitonclick()
draw_square()
```

Comment: Please show us the error

Answer (score 0):

You've made a couple of mistakes in your program.  First, the `window.exitonclick()` isn't indented properly such that you're referencing a local variable of `draw_square()` from outside the function.  Your insanely narrow, one space indentation was likely a contributor to this issue.

The next mistake is `brad.shape("yellow")` as yellow isn't a shape, it's a color.  Also, the comments in `draw_square()` appear to be on the wrong lines.  Some might not consider that a mistake, but I do.

Your code reworked to fix the above and lay it out in a more logical fashion for turtle programming:

```
import turtle

def draw_square(a_turtle):
    a_turtle.forward(100) # move forward
    a_turtle.right(90) # turn pen right 90 degrees
    a_turtle.forward(100)
    a_turtle.right(90)
    a_turtle.forward(100)
    a_turtle.right(90)
    a_turtle.forward(100)
    a_turtle.right(90)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("red")

brad = turtle.Turtle()
brad.shape("turtle")
brad.color("yellow")
brad.speed("slow")

draw_square(brad)

turtle.mainloop()
```